# Scala forall to compare two lists?

Tags: scala

If I wan't to see if each element in a list corresponds correctly to an element of the same index in another list, could I use forall to do this? For example something like

```
val p=List(2,4,6)
val q=List(1,2,3)
p.forall(x=>x==q(x)/2)
```

I understand that the x isn't an index of of q, and thats the problem I'm having, is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The most idiomatic way to handle this situation would be to zip the two lists:

```
scala> p.zip(q).forall { case (x, y) => x == y * 2 }
res0: Boolean = true
```

You could also use `zipped`, which can be slightly more efficient in some situations, as well as letting you be a bit more concise (or maybe just obfuscated):

```
scala> (p, q).zipped.forall(_ == _ * 2)
res1: Boolean = true
```

Note that both of these solutions will silently ignore extra elements if the lists don't have the same length, which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is probably to use `zip`

```
p.zip(q).forall{case (fst, snd) => fst == snd * 2}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sequences from scala collection library have `corresponds` method which does exactly what you need:

```
p.corresponds(q)(_ == _ * 2)
```

It will return false if `p` and `q` are of different length.